# How to use ggplot2 to do boxplot by counts by group?

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-structures

I now have a dataframe like this:

```
Area  Type  Group
15.4   B2     1
16.3   B2     1
23.1   B3     1
40.9   B4     1
2.3    B4     2
4.6    B3     2
7.8    B3     2
...    ...   ...
```

There are 3 kinds of types: B2, B3 and B4; and there are 10 groups for **each type**:1-10.

I want to do a boxplot of 3 types, which means x-axis are types. And each 10 data for each group, which means y is the numbers of **each group of this type**.

in a word, like this:
[image]

I tried `ggplot(data, aes(x = type, y = group, fill = type)) + 
  geom_boxplot()`but not works.

How can I do this?

Comment: Try this `ggplot(df, aes(x = Type, y = Group, fill = Type)) + geom_boxplot()`, it'll work..

Comment: it's not work. for it only take the group as a number, but thanks

Comment: Can you `dput` your data?

Comment: okay I will give a try!

Comment: Do you want the boxplots to span the `Area`? If `Type` is a, well, type and `group` is a, well, group, the only other variable I can think of plotting is `Area`. Something like `ggplot(df, aes(x = Type, y = Area, fill = Type))+geom_boxplot()`